# iOS Simulator cannot open Application using Package URL

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently developing a Flutter application and trying to make Azure AD B2C work. Everything works fine except the redirect back to the application.

So I've tried triggering opening the application by entering the URL "com.companyname://auth" into Safari. On my smartphone, this directs me to the application perfectly fine, however on the simulator the error "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid." is shown.

I have verified the package URL of the application, but it seems to be correct.

If you have any ideas on this topic, please let me know, because I have no other idea for debugging this issue.

Comment: I don't believe the simulators support all the features of deep linking.